# Frigidaire works after shaking?

Tags: repair, refrigerator

Have a frigidaire refrigerator that's a few years old. Noticed and odd problem - the refrigerator is dead when the door is opened (light off and compressor silent, not cooling) - almost like it's unplugged. But a gentle nudge or shake turns it on.

Any ideas ? First I thought it was the plug which is behind the refrigerator, but that's plugged it firmly and the no problem with socket.

It doesn't seem like a thermostat or temp problem because even the light is off with door opened.

Comment: The light not working could be a blown bulb, or a stuck door-switch. Or even just an empty socket with no bulb at all.

Comment: Sounds like a broken wire possibly in the power cable with the plug.